# How do I keep the new line/line break/end of line in a file consistent across mac and windows

Tags: dropbox, textedit

I use DropBox on both a windows and a mac.

Whenever I add lines to a .txt file on my mac and sync it with DropBox to my windows, the "new lines" are skrewed up when reading the file on my windows, and vice verse.

My mac insists to use it own form of new lines even so that the file was created with a different type of new lines. The end result is a file with mixed new line types.

I know that new lines are different on windows and mac os x (and on linux for that matter) and I know that this is the problem.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

I would expect **textedit** in OS X to detect the type of new line used and stick with it.

Is there anyway that I can accomplish that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which editors and viewers do you use?

[This](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=22243) topic describes how to set newline in [BBedit](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1727559/BBeditPrefs-ScreenShot.png) and [Textmate](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1727559/TextMatePrefs-ScreenShot.png). Also you can use [TextWrangler](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textwrangler/id404010395?mt=12) and Notepad++ which are freeware

**PS:** I commonly use [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) in Windows and Mac ([MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)). In this editor I do ":set fileformat=dos" to convert to CR-LF

Comment: I currently use Textedit in OS X and Notepad/Wordpad on windows.
So my problem seems to be Textedit. 
I am not looking for a system wide change (not that I even think it is possible, nor desirable)

Comment: System wide change for this setting is not possible. By the way, you can give a try for [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and TextWrangler(AppStore) which are free and understand both CR-LF and LF notations

Comment: I will give TextWrangler a shot, but I still hope for a  solution for the build in Textedit in OS X for others that stumble across the same problem. It would be a .pref hack or there might be other ways.

Comment: Notepad in Windows like Textedit in Mac OS X is software with very limited functions. Other way is use other formats such as RTF or simple *doc (so you have use wordpad in windows)